# The type or namespace name 'AdaptiveCards' could not be found

Tags: c#, azure-bot-service, adaptive-cards

I've tried both `using Microsoft.AdaptiveCards;` and `using AdaptiveCards;` but when I perform a build for my Azure Web App Bot I get the following error:

> Dialogs\BasicLuisDialog.cs(17,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace
>     name 'AdaptiveCards' could not be found (are you missing a using
>     directive or an assembly reference?)

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you added the AdaptiveCards nuget package? https://www.nuget.org/packages/AdaptiveCards

Comment: I added `<package id="AdaptiveCards" version="1.0.3" targetFramework="net46" />` to packages.config. Which then returned this on build: `Restoring NuGet package AdaptiveCards.1.0.3.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/adaptivecards/1.0.3/adaptivecards.1.0.3.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/adaptivecards/1.0.3/adaptivecards.1.0.3.nupkg 473ms
Installing AdaptiveCards 1.0.3.
Adding package 'AdaptiveCards.1.0.3' to folder 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\packages'

Installed:
    1 package(s) to packages.config projects`

Comment: Ok, installing the package takes more than just adding it to the packages.config file. You need to use something like `nuget restore` afterwards so it can actually download and install the package.

Comment: Looks like any `nuget` commands I run don't do anything and I have to CTRL + C to cancel. I'm using the Azure App Service Editor to edit my C# Web App Bot.

Comment: Ok, then I'm sorry but I can't help you any more, don't have any experience in azure.

Comment: That's cool thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dale,
you need to add a reference to the AdaptiveCard assembly file in your project's csproj file.

Find the file 'Microsoft.Bot.Sample.LuisBot.csproj' and open it for editing. 
Find the section named 'ItemGroup' and add the following piece of code:

```
<Reference Include="AdaptiveCards, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>packages\AdaptiveCards.1.0.3\lib\net452\AdaptiveCards.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

You told your code file what assembly you needed but you haven't told the project where to find it.